# how to extract and remove the header of a windows PE (portable executable) file?

Tags: portable-executable, malware, malware-detection

I am working on an assignment in packed malware analysis, in which I have to extract i.e. remove the header file of a PE malware and then I have to fragment the data. But I am unable to find out how to read and extract the header of a PE file.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not taking better effort but well.. it is your assignment right? :)

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDosHeader;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNtHeaders;

CreateFile("file.exe",...);
ReadFile(..,ptrBuf,...); 

pDosHeader = ptrBuf;
pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(((PUCHAR)pDosHeader) + pDosHeader->e_lfanew);
```

Duh.. did you not pay attention during the class?